# enviar array por url con javascript y acceder a sus valores con php

Tags: php, javascript

En el html recojo un string separado por comas. por ejemplo:

3,6,8,2

este string tiene que ser inmediatamente convertido en javascript a un array. Para ello recojo el value del input y hago un split por comas:

```
const inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;

var array = inputValue.split(",");
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. Ahora quiero enviarlo por la URL.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', `controller.php?array=${array}`, true);

  xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);

            } else {
              console.log('errooooor')
            }
        }

        xhr.send();
```

Cuando lo recibo en el controlador me encuentro con que el GET me lo devuelve en forma de string:

```
(var_dump($_GET['array']); //me devuelve esto: string(7) "3,6,8,2"
```

Lo que voy a necesitar es acceder a cada posición para hacer operaciones con esos números pero si por ejemplo, intento acceder a la posición 1 (echo $_GET['array'][1], me devuelve esto "," en lugar de "6".

Creo que es porque el controller no lo está recibiendo como un array, sino como un string.

Espero que se entienda.
¿Alguien sabría decirme en dónde me he perdido?

Comment: ¿ Estás absolutamente seguro de que `var_dump($_GET['array']);` te muestra eso que dices ? Es **imposible** que te diga que la longitud de la cadena es menor que el total de caracteres.

Comment: Si hago var_dump($array) me devuelve el array array:4 [▼
  0 => "3"
  1 => "6"
  2 => "8"
  3 => "2"
], has probado a enviar el array con una llamada ajax por post? y luego hacer json_decode en tu controlador

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo que quieres hacer. Si haces el `split` en Javascript no tiene sentido luego hacer `explode` en PHP, ambas cosas hacen lo mismo. Entonces, o lo mandas ya separado desde JS o lo mandas sin separar y haces el `explode` en PHP.

Comment: En el explode, te falta `_` en la variable del get.

Comment: el array tiene que ser construido en el javascript y enviado como tal por GET. el problema es que haciendo el split en el js, en el controller.php hago var_dump($_GET['array'] y tengo esto: string(7) "3,6,8,2"

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es recoger cada uno de los valores y sumarlos. pero cuando intento acceder a la primera posición echo $_GET['array'][1] me devuelve ","

Comment: esto ocurre porque $_GET['array] está en forma de string y no de array ¿No es así?

Comment: edito pregunta para que se vea como lo envío

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Opción #1

Como menciono **@A. Cedano** o le haces el `split()` en **JS** o el `explode()` en **PHP** no tiene caso que hagas los dos.

Puedes simplemente mandar el input tal cual con las comas y hacerle el **explode()**:

```
//$datos = "3,6,8,2"; // $_GET['array'];
$datos = explode(',', $_GET['array']);
var_dump($datos);
```

Esto te da como salida:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "8" [3]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Para sumar los valores del arreglo basta con:

```
$suma = array_sum($datos); // 19
var_dump($suma); // resultado: int(19)
```

> Opción #2

Para poder enviar el arreglo desde **JS** lo mandas como **JSON**.

```
const inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
var array = inputValue.split(",");
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'controller.php?array=' + JSON.stringify(array), true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
        console.log('errooooor')
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

Y en **PHP** lo recibes y procesas así:

```
$arreglo = (array)json_decode($_GET['array']; // Recibes el arreglo
$suma = array_sum($arreglo); // Sumas el arreglo
```

Comment: el array tiene que ser construido en el javascript y enviado como tal por GET. el problema es que haciendo el split en el js, en el controller.php hago var_dump($_GET['array'] y tengo esto: string(7) "3,6,8,2"

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es recoger cada uno de los valores y sumarlos. pero cuando intento acceder a la primera posición echo $_GET['array'][1] me devuelve ","

Comment: edito pregunta para que se vea como lo envío

Comment: Si lo notas por eso puse // $_GET['array'] aun lado, porque yo puse el texto en la variable como ejemplo, tu en su lugar pondras el $_GET['array']. Obviamente si dices que ya estas recibiendo bien el GET entonces por eso te puse nadamas el texto de ejemplo. Solo es cuestión que tú le pases el GET y ya el explode que haga su trabajo, ya una vez realizado el xplode puedes hacer un foreach del arreglo y sumar los valores.

Comment: Ya te edite la respuesta agregándole él como sumar los valores y seteando tu variable $_GET en $datos.

Comment: ok pero... Estás haciendo split en el js y luego un explode en php... ¿No habíamos dicho que esto no es buena práctica?

Comment: Amigo que dices?, si te fijas yo te estoy comentando en la respuesta que tienes que enviar los datos sin hacer el split. Te dije que enviaras el input así tal cual con los números con comas.

Comment: es lo que te he dicho en el primer comentario. El array tiene que ser construido en el js, o sea que tengo que hacer el split.

Comment: No necesitas hacer un arreglo en js, solo tu cadena de texto, el explode se encarga de hacer el arreglo en php, tu solo manda tu cadena por get y recibela en php, realiza el explode así como te lo puse y listo. No requieres de más.

Comment: amigo es que no es una opción. Debo recibir el array ya construido.

Comment: @InfiniteRoads Ya te agregue las 2 opciones (1 y 2), la 2 haces el array desde js y lo procesas y listo. Y en otra ocasión postula la pregunta especificando que es forzosamente realizarlo de una manera. Eso ya no debe darte ningún problema.

Comment: transformarlo en JSON ya lo había probado. Haciéndolo tal y como me dices en la opción 2, me devuelve: "Array". Sigo sin poder acceder a sus valores.

Comment: Ya está solucionado. El problema es que para ahorra líneas de código estaba haciendo esto: echo json_decode($_GET['array']);

Comment: Haciéndolo como lo haces tú $arreglo = (array)json_decode($_GET['array']; y luego print_r($arreglo[0]); sí que me permite acceder a cada posición (en este caso la 0).

Comment: No entiendo por qué no funciona si no lo guardas en una variable pero gracias por las molestias.